# Using xUnit.net Console Runner With Mono

Tags: c#, mono, xunit, xunit.net

This seems like "too easy" of a subject for a question on here, but I'm honestly having a hard time finding any information on the subject.

Basically, here's the gist. We have a couple projects across different platforms  (Windows and Mac, for instance) written in C#. We use xUnit for our unit tests via xUnit.net, which are shared between the platforms. I'm trying to get these tests to run in the xUnit.net console runner, as described [here](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#add-xunit-runner-ref), but I can't seem to get the runner to work in mono. Is there something extra I need to do? The following is what I'm trying to do via command line:

```
 mono [REPOSITORY_PATH]/Apple/Source/Solutions/packages/xunit.runner.console.2.1.0/tools/xunit.console.exe "[REPOSITORY_PATH]/Apple/Source/Platform/Mac/MacXunitTests/bin/Debug/[PROJECT_NAME].Tests.Mac.dll"
```

The following is the error I received:

```
 xUnit.net Console Runner (32-bit .NET 4.0.30319.17020)
 Can't find custom attr constructor image: /private/var/folders/0p/s4d1k4150zd2v8b0y1q2nz902v4jm6/T/d724bcb6-cce1-4430-b645-6dadd980c2ee/d724bcb6-cce1-4430-b645-6dadd980c2ee/assembly/shadow/6755efca/b6f5411e_d1a0aed4_00000002/xunit.execution.desktop.dll mtoken: 0x0a000009
 Unhandled loader error: 7, (null) xunit.core, Version=2.0.0.2929, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c Xunit.Sdk.PlatformSpecificAssemblyAttribute
 * Assertion: should not be reached at loader.c:298
```

Comment: I'm running Xamarin Studio that is based on Mono, I have a PCL project with some logic classes there. I have another Project that tests the Code in the PCL. I can run that tests in the Xamarin Studio Addin and it work good. Now i want to run the same tests in the console, but i can't find the were to get the xunit.console.exe rum the tests. (im on a mac)

Comment: You have to install the proper nuget package. xUnit.Net [Runner: Console] is the package name. Check out this link: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#add-xunit-runner-ref

Comment: I downloaded the console runner via nuget command line and run the tests via mono passing the xunit and tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a result of using an older version of xUnit.net. We were using some kind of release candidate version of 2.0, which was causing the error I posted. Removing the nuget package and reinstalling 2.0 seems to make the tests runnable.

I've now discovered that the tests are failing in the console runner, but this appears to be related to some error loading an assembly in a collection fixture, but this is outside the purview of the original question.